# What is the difference between Genetic and Cellular Genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between Genetic algorithm and Cellular Genetic algorithm? All what I know is that in Cellular the individuals cannot mate randomly, they interact with their neighbors only. What are other differences between the two algorithms?

Comment: How is the somewhat detailed description here ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_evolutionary_algorithm ) not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference lies in how mating pairs are chosen. There is quite a lot more that can be said but it mostly revolves around implementation.

The usual method is to select two individuals randomly and weighted so that the more fit individuals are likely to be chosen for mating.

In the cellular implementation, the individuals are connected in some way and are more likely to mate with closer neighbors while also taking fitness into account. The connection could be implied by placing individuals in a grid or it could be explicit by placing them on a graph. This tends to produce localized optimizations.

So, another key difference is how the problem is approached. If local optimization makes sense in the context of the problem then cellular algorithms are more suited. Otherwise, they can just waste time and in extreme cases, perhaps, always fail.